# CSS3 transitions + display none + prevent overscroll

Tags: html, animation, css

So if you're not already familiar, CSS3 transitions do not animate `display: none` since it removes the targeted element from the DOM altogether.  So here's my issue.  I have a sidebar with larger popup divs that appear on hover.  Unfortunately Since I can only transition on `visibility: hidden` and `opacity: 0` I have overscroll due to the visibly hidden divs being included in the layout and thus making a very long popup which is accounted for in the page's scrollbar.

Looking for some creative solutions for how I can still animate without having the scrollbar all screwed up.

I'm developing local so I don't have a live example to show, but you can see the problem in this screencast: http://dreamstarstudios.com/screencasts/2011-09-27_2111.swf

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried removing the elements after the animation using JS?

Comment: I know that JS is an ideal combo for this, but having trouble conceptualizing, can you elaborate a bit?  jQuery would be great here...

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the question better after looking at the video. I made a "hovercard" a while back that calculated screen size to ensure it was always displayed within the bounds of the window (preventing scrollbar). See this code: https://github.com/kaimallea/Starcraft-2-Hovercards/blob/master/js/sc2-hovercards.js#L1727 and let me know if that gives you a better idea

Comment: That seems close, but will it adjust and permit the overflow (scrollbars) when the element is hovered?  Seems like a bit of a special unique problem I'm having with this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming your popup is absolutely positioned so you could do the following:

1. While hidden, set the popup `top` to a huge negative value.  This moves it off the screen and gets rid of the scrollbar.
2. On hover, set the `top` to the correct value and transition the `opacity` value.
3. Make sure that your CSS `transition` rules are only for the `opacity` property.

**HTML**

```
<a href="">Popup go now</a>
<div class="popup">
    My cat's breath smells like cat food...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popup {
   position: absolute;
   top: -2000px;
   opacity: 0;

   transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover + .popup,
.popup:hover {
   top: 30px;
   opacity: 1;   
}
```

Here's the above [in action](http://jsfiddle.net/56Se6/).

*Update*: To add the left swing, and clean up the mouseout animation, you can use the following code:

```
.popup {
   position: absolute;
   top: -2000px;
   width: 300px;
   left: 0;
   opacity: 0;

   /* Animate opacity, left and top  
      opacity and left should animate over 1s, top should animate over 0s
      opacity and left should begin immediately.  Top should start after 1s. */
   transition-property: opacity, left, top;
   transition-duration: 1s, 1s, 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 1s;
}

a:hover + .popup,
.popup:hover {
   top: 30px;
   left: 30px;
   opacity: 1;  

   /* All animations should start immediately */
   transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

It does this as follows:

1. Animation for multiple properties are specified (opacity, left, top).
2. `transition-delay` prevents the top value from being changed until the opacity and left animations are complete.  The trick here is that when the element is `:hover`, there is no delay (opacity, left and top animations all start at once).  However once `:hover` is no longer active, the top animation waits 1 second before starting.  This gives opacity and left enough time to finish.

Here's the [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/56Se6/4/).

Comment: This is very close!  But check out my video here: http://dreamstarstudios.com/screencasts/2011-09-27_2111.swf ... I'm transitioning on both opacity and position.  Is there any way to combine what you've showed here with the "swing" effect so that the position can also be animated?

Comment: and yes I might just need to forget the swing effect :/

Comment: Just added some edits - your left swing can remain in full effect (and I figured out how to clean up the mouseout animation to boot).

Comment: I'm incredibly impressed!  Can't get it working on my working version just yet, but it certainly works in your example... need to hunt stuff down :/

Comment: For the record, I tracked down the bug on my end, I wish I could up-vote this 5 times, this is an AMAZING solution!

Comment: Thanks - I'm pretty happy I found that `:hover` and `transition-delay` trick too.

Comment: Brilliant. This deserves the Nobel prize for outstanding CSS achievements :)