# Fade-in and appear, fade-out and disappear using only css?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I am trying to create a menu that fades in/out when a button is clicked, and I am trying to do the animation using CSS transitions.

Here is a sample of what I want to achieve

```
#menu{
    background: red;
    display: block;    
    overflow: hidden;   
    position: absolute;
    width: 182px;
    top: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    /* The menu must not be clickable/cover the UI once hidden */
    left: -100000px;

    /*
    The left property must change after the 
    opacity is zero and before it starts to
    increase
    */
    transition: opacity 0.25s 0.1s, left 0s; /* ??? */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s 0.1, left 0s; /* Safari */
}

#menu.open{
    opacity: 1;
    left: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AzKAk/5/

Of course that only works half way, when the menu appears it DOES fade in, but when it has to fade out, this must happen after the element has its proper position.

Is it possible to do such thing using only CSS3?

Comment: yes it is possible but I don't understand what you want?

Comment: I want to make the menu toggle with fade in/out but I don't want it to stay there when it's opacity is zero, causing the ui behind it to be unusable. I actually want it to be out of the screen or `display:none`, but only after it's opacity is zero

Comment: http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337 look at this, I hope this could help you.

Comment: or this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577308/css3-transitions-display-none-prevent-overscroll

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your intention is to have the menu appear/disappear in-place without any movement.

To do that you actually have to use a combination of two properties: `opacity`, and `display`.

The change in opacity will make the menu disappear, but once it reaches `opacity:0` it will be invisible but still exist and receive user interaction.

So, you have to make sure that after the opacity transition is done, you have to change the `display` to `none`.

You can do this using the `transitionend` event (`webkitTransitionEnd` on Chome/Safari).

Your code would look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/daniran/GfbVV/

I'm using jQuery in the example, but you can just as easily register the listeners directly using `ontransitionend` property;